# Using chain rule on a two-particle quantum system.

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics

The 2 (two) particles have masses $m_1$,$m_2$ and their position and momentum variables are $\mathbf{r}_1$,$\mathbf{r}_2$,$\mathbf{p}_1$,$\mathbf{p}_2$ respectively with potential $V(\mathbf{r})$ with $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2$.

The Hamiltonian is $$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2m_1}\hat{\mathbf{p}}_1^2+\frac{1}{2m_2}\hat{\mathbf{p}}_2^2 + V(\hat{\mathbf{r}}_1-\hat{\mathbf{r}}_2)$$

The wave function $\Psi$ for this system obeys the SE

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t} = \hat{\mathbf{H}}\Psi$$

The problem I have is the actual maths behind the following question:
introducing COM and relative displacement coordinates, $$\mathbf{R}=\frac{m_1}{M}\mathbf{r_1}+\frac{m_2}{M}\mathbf{r_2}, \quad (M=m_1+m_2)$$

Use the extended chain rule to show $-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{R}}\Phi=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{\mathbf{r_1}}}\Psi -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{\mathbf{r_2}}}\Psi$ and from this conclude $\hat{\mathbf{P}}=\hat{\mathbf{p_1}}+\hat{\mathbf{p_2}}$

Comment: Cool question. What have are your thoughts on it so far? Exactly what part so you want help with?

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure where to start to be honest. Like how does the extended chain rule work on the LHS above?

Comment: It might be important to tell us what $\Phi$ is. The spacial part of the wave function, I assume? Remember that the derivative of a scalar w.r.t a vector is a column vector, that is $$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \underline{R}}
=\bigg[\frac{\partial f}{\partial R_x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial R_y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial R_z}\bigg]^{\mathrm{T}}$$

Use the definition of $\underline{R}$ to work out its $x$, $y$, and $z$ coords.

Comment: The $\Phi$ is the wave function in its new coordinates, where $\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,t) =: \Phi(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{r},t)$

Answer (score 1):

(first off big up LLU ;) ), good luck with the resit. What we did was
reaarange $\underline{r_1}$, $\underline{r_2}$ for $\underline{R}$ and $\underline{r}$. So you should get

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{r_1} &= \frac{\underline{R}M + m_2 \underline{r_2}}{M}\\
\underline{r_2} &= \frac{\underline{R}M + m_2 \underline{r_2}}{M} - \underline{r}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
then for the equations all you have to do is start with left hand side and work with right in the original equation $\psi(\underline{r_1},\underline{r_2};t)$ = $\phi(\underline{R},\underline{r};t)$

so you multiply by $-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \underline{R}}$
therefore we do that for the wave function $\psi$ but remember that $\underline{R}$ and $\underline{r}$ are parametrised by $\underline{r_1}$ and $\underline{r_2}$ so you need to implement a chain rule
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \underline{R}} \phi = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \underline{R}} \psi \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
but expand with chain rule so
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \underline{R}} \phi = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \underline{r_1}} \frac{\partial \underline{r_1}}{\partial \underline{R}} +  
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \underline{r_2}} \frac{\partial \underline{r_2}}{\partial \underline{R}}
\end{equation}
If you work through with your definitions for $\underline{r_1}$ and $\underline{r_2}$ you'll get the $\frac{\partial \underline{r_1}}{\partial \underline{R}} = \frac{\partial \underline{r_2}}{\partial \underline{R}} = 1$
and thus you've proved your desired result. Just apply the same process again for the $\frac{\partial}{\partial \underline{r}}$ part and you get the results you're after. Hope this helps